# PHP - Parse Nested JSON Array via Loop

Tags: php, json

I'm working with some JSON data like this:

```
    {
  "attachments": [
    {
      "content": "<base 64 encoded attachment>", 
      "content_type": "image/jpeg", 
      "original_name": "image000000.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "content": "<base 64 encoded attachment>", 
      "content_type": "image/gif", 
      "original_name": "gif0001.jpg"
    }
  ], 
  "source_number": "++614567890"
}
```

I need to loop through all the attachments array. I can get individual elements like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($jsonobj, true);
echo $arr[attachments][0]["content_type"]; // returns image/jpeg
```

but I can't work out the syntax to loop through all of the attachments array and retrieve the values for each of these, something like this pseudo code:

```
    foreach($arr[attachments] as $key => $value) {
  $contentType = $arr[attachments][0]["content_type" ;
  $content = $arr[attachments][0]["content" ;
  $originalName = $arr[attachments][0]["original_name" ;
}
```

that will generate a variable in the loop for each item in the attachments array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `$key`, you just need the `$value`. In the loop, `$value` is associative array that has the keys `content`, `content_type` and `original_name`:

```
foreach($arr["attachments"] as $value) {
  $contentType = $value["content_type"];
  $content = $value["content"];
  $originalName = $value["original_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there: `$value['content_type']` (and so on) inside your loop will do the trick. (The `$key` is superfluous.)

Oh and you should use `$arr['attachments']` instead of `$arr[attachments]` probably.